# Does Ranar the Ever-Watchful's ability stack with Day of the Dragons?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Ranar the Ever-Watchful](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ranar%20the%20Ever-Watchful) has the ability

> Whenever one or more cards are put into exile from your hand or a spell or ability you control exiles one or more permanents from the battlefield, create a 1/1 white Spirit creature token with flying.

If I have Ranar on the battlefield with *N* creatures and play [Day of the Dragons](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Day%20of%20the%20Dragons):

> When Day of the Dragons enters the battlefield, exile all creatures you control. Then create that many 5/5 red Dragon creature tokens with flying.

Will I get the tokens for Ranar's ability and all creatures turned to dragons and end up with *N* 5/5 dragons and *N* 1/1 white spirits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuzz's answer is mostly correct, but I want to address where they explain the number of spirits:

> To create multiple spirits Ranar's ability would have to not have the "one or more" clause in it.

This part isn't exactly right, there are two wordings that would have created N spirits:

1. Whenever ... a spell or ability you control exiles **a** permanent from the battlefield, create **a** 1/1 white Spirit
2. Whenever ... a spell or ability you control exiles **one or more** permanents from the battlefield, create **that many** 1/1 white Spirits

1 is the version that Becuzz mentions in their answer, this would mean Ranar triggers once for each permanent being exiled, with each trigger creating one 1/1 spirit token. 2 on the other hand triggers only once, but creates multiple tokens from the single triggered ability on the stack. This difference can matter in a few ways, mostly in countering (one trigger versus many triggers) and other effects that watch for "one or more" creatures entering.

Answer (score 5):

You will end up with N 5/5 dragons and 1 1/1 spirit.

Ranar's ability can look back in time to see how many things were exiled with Day of the Dragons:

> **603.10a** Some zone-change triggers look back in time. These are leaves-the-battlefield abilities, abilities that trigger when a card
> leaves a graveyard, and abilities that trigger when an object that all
> players can see is put into a hand or library.

So Ranar's ability will see N creatures get exiled.  However it won't create N spirits because Ranar's ability is worded (emphasis mine)

> Whenever ... a spell or ability you control exiles **one or more**
> permanents from the battlefield, create **a** 1/1 white Spirit

To create multiple spirits Ranar's ability would have to not have the "one or more" clause in it.